# Fluentd buffering issue

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring, fluentd

I am new to fluentd tool. We have recently introduced fluentd in our logging pipeline. We are using both forwarder and aggregator which then pushes the data to ElasticSearch. The problem is whenever ES node is unreachable fluentd buffer fills up.
This is the following configuration used for fluentd:

```
   @type file
   chunk_limit_size 32MB
   total_limit_size 64GB
   flush_interval 10s
   overflow_action throw_exception
   flush_thread_count 4
   retry_type exponential_backoff
   retry_exponential_backoff_base 2
   retry_max_interval 60

   @type memory
   chunk_limit_size 32MB
   total_limit_size 16GB
   flush_interval 10s
   overflow_action throw_exception
   flush_thread_count 4
   retry_type exponential_backoff
   retry_exponential_backoff_base 2
   retry_max_interval 60
```

Comment: You have not really mentioned any ES or Fluentd versions. Please add more information in to your description. Is it the file or the memory buffer that fills up ? And also why have you used such a large chunk limit ? I suggest you look at the various options in https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/buffer-section#buffering-parameters such as the compress.

Comment: ES version  is - 5.6.9 and fluentd version is 3.1.1

Comment: Also, is it okay to use both file and memory buffer?

Comment: @khushboo sharma create an elasticsearch cluster :)

Comment: There's some discussion of sensible limits at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/logging/config/efk-logging-fluentd.html https://github.com/openshift/origin-aggregated-logging/pull/418